# How to get proper API data for angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, api, express

I created an API service with nodejs, express and mongodb. It's working properly when I test it with postman and even on the browser. However, when I try to do the same from angular app, it gives a weird response.

This is a get request I made from postman :
[image]

The angular code for api service :

```
url = 'http://localhost:3000';
getList() {
  return this.http.get(this.url);
}
```

When I do following in the app.component.ts

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.taskapi.getList()));
```

this is what I see in the console :

```
{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":true,"value":{"url":"http://localhost:3000","body":null,"reportProgress":false,"withCredentials":false,"responseType":"json","method":"GET","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"params":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null},"urlWithParams":"http://localhost:3000"}},"operator":{"concurrent":1}},"operator":{}},"operator":{}}
```

I want the same response in angular as I get from postman. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should subscribe the observable to get the result. Observables are Lazy , unless you subscribe , it wont initiate the call

```js
    getList() {
      return this.http.get(this.url);
    }
    list:any;
    this.taskapi.getList().subscribe((response)=>{
         this.list = response;
        //here you will get the response
    });
```

Also you can use angular **async** pipe which will automatically subscribe and unsubscribe for you

```html
    <div *ngFor='let item of yourObservableList | async'>

    </div>
```

Comment: @San Glad to here!. Save this as an array means , are you trying to post again to server ? could you please explain what you are trying to doing?

Comment: @San if you want to iterate as an array in html , please see the updated answer. You can keep the response array in another property collection and can use in html without async pipe.

Comment: nvm, I got it working. I was just trying to save the response in a local variable so I can access later. It turned out to be a type issue. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your getList() function is returning an `Observable`, that's what `this.http.get` return.

Just subscribe to the Observable and print the response, like so:

```
this.taskapi.getList().subscribe(
  res =>
  {
    console.log(res);
  },
  err =>
  {
    /*Error handling*/
  }
)
```